# Change base url of laravel app

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

Currently I am developing a site for a client using Laravel 5.1.

On the testing server it is `example.com/sites/project/public/index.php/`, but on the clients server it will just be `example.com/`.

Is there a way to set the sites base url to point to `/sites/project/` instead of the root when using our testing server, and then using the root as the base url on the clients server? Because currently I have to go and put in the base url before every link and change it every time I change servers - which is bad practice.

**EDIT**

I mainly want to do this when using assets, so the link to the asset points to the correct folder. Currently it points to `example.com/assets/...` and on the testing server it points to the same thing, when it should be pointing to `example.com/sites/project/public/assets/...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the asset function will append the url you give it to the location of the index.php file,

so if in server 1 you url is example.com/sites/1/public/
and in server 2 your url is example2.com/

and the asset is live inside the public folder the same code will work inside both url, that's the purpose of url helpers.
so you don't need to do anything it will work out of the box